# jQuery addClass foreach ul.sub-menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dom, wordpress-theming

WordPress does't give `ul.sub-menu` any unique classes (yet)...

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-primary" class="nav">
 <li>News
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>Local</li>
    <li>Politics</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Sports
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>Baseball</li>
    <li>Football</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Opinion
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>Forums</li>
    <li>Blogs</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
```

Using jQuery I can .addClass to the first one only.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

     $('ul.sub-menu').addClass (function() {
         return "item-" + $(this).index();
});
```

The result is this:

```
<ul id="menu-primary" class="nav">
 <li>News
   <ul class="sub-menu item-1">
    <li>Local</li>
    <li>Politics</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Sports
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>Baseball</li>
    <li>Football</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Opinion
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>Forums</li>
    <li>Blogs</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
```

That's great, but **how do I assign a unique class to EACH** `ul.sub-menu`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code, should do the work.

```
$(function(){        
     $('ul.sub-menu').addClass (function(idx) {         
         return "item-" + idx;
     });
 });
```

you can test it here : http://jsfiddle.net/dvdPd/17/

Comment: GREAT! nice! (or use: {idx++;  return "item-" + idx; } to start count from 1

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested it.. but .each() would be the function you need.

```
$('ul.sub-menu').each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass("item-" + index);
});
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) Here's the documentation: [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)