# better sub-level ul classes with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-lists

Is there a better way of writing the following preferably with unlimited sub-levels...?

```
$('#menu-primary-navigation li > ul.sub-menu').addClass('lvl-1');
$('#menu-primary-navigation li li > ul.sub-menu').removeClass('lvl-1').addClass('lvl-2');
$('#menu-primary-navigation li li li > ul.sub-menu').removeClass('lvl-2').addClass('lvl-3');
$('#menu-primary-navigation li li li li > ul.sub-menu').removeClass('lvl-3').addClass('lvl-4');
```

Please note that the whole menu is created dynamically so I can't add classes manually to each level.

This is an example of the starting code:

```
        <ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="menu">

           <li><a href="#">Top Level</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Top Level</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-level 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-level 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Top Level</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-level 1</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-level 2</a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-level 3</a>
                                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Sub-level 4</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Sub-level 4</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-level 3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-level 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-level 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
​
```

Comment: Could you post the code which generates the menu. This should really be done at that point in the process.

Comment: The code is generated via php – I'm using this on a WordPress Menu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery addClass foreach ul.sub-menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985281/jquery-addclass-foreach-ul-sub-menu)